# Binding Json data with ajax/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

i have sql script and has to encode to json (data.php), i want to bind json data from data.php

here is the script from data.php :

```
switch ($data){
    case "report-reg-perday":
        $query=("SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(reqtime, '%Y %D %M') AS 'reqtime', COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS 'jumlah' FROM users_demoid GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(reqtime,'%Y %D %M') ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(reqtime) ASC ");
        break;
    case "report-reg-perweek":
        $query=("SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(reqtime, '%U') AS 'reqtime', COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS 'jumlah' FROM users_demoid GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(reqtime,'%U') ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(reqtime) ASC ");
        break;
    case "report-reg-permonth":
        $query=("SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(reqtime, '%M') AS 'reqtime', COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS 'jumlah' FROM users_demoid GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(reqtime,'%M') ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(reqtime) ASC ");
        break;
    default:
        $query=("SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(reqtime) AS 'reqtime', COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS 'jumlah' FROM users_demoid GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(reqtime,'%U') ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(reqtime) ASC ");
        }
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());
//get data and store in a json array
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    //$date=date("l, F j, Y H:i:s",$row['reqtime']);
            $orders[] = array(
                'reqtime' => $row['reqtime'],
                'jumlah' => $row['jumlah'],
            );
}

echo json_encode($orders);
```

i want to bind 'reqtime' and 'jumlah' to my javascript/ajax :

```
    $(function ()  
                {
   var dataSource = [
    { request_time: 'reqtime', total: 'jumlah'}
];


$("#chartContainer").dxChart({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    equalBarWidth: {
        width: 50
    },
    commonSeriesSettings: {
        argumentField: "request_time",
        type: "bar",
        hoverMode: "allArgumentPoints",
        selectionMode: "allArgumentPoints",
        label: {
            visible: true,
            format: "fixedPoint",
            precision: 0
        }
    },
    series: [
        { valueField: "total", name: "Registrant" }
    ],
    title: "Report",
    legend: {
        verticalAlignment: "bottom",
        horizontalAlignment: "center"
    },
    pointClick: function (point) {
        this.select();
    }
});
}
```

hhe im nubie in json, ajax, and javascript

> Blockquote

thanks before.

Comment: i want to bind my json data to my jquery chart

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var dataSource;
$.ajax({
   url:'data.php',
   dataType:'json',
   success: function(d){
      if(d.length){
         dataSource = d;
         // code for dxchart;
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: what was function(d) for ?

Comment: Its `success callback response` getting from `data.php`. Read http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Comment: do i must place this to `[
    { request_time: 'reqtime', total: 'jumlah'}
];` ? after `success: function(d){
      if(d.length){
         dataSource = d;
         // code for dxchart;
      }`